# How to loop back "headphones" audio

Tags: sound, 20.04, pulseaudio, raspberrypi, jack

I am running Ubuntu 20.04 on a Raspberry pi and I would like to record the output from the speakers connected to the jack output of the rpi so that another application can receive its signal.
I have already tried with pulseaudio (pactl and pavcontrol) but I don't really know how these tools work, so any help is appreciated.